# masonry appended not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

I first try to append a template but got the same issue where it fails to append it to the projects element.
Then tried to just append a jquery object called div and it does not seem to append it to the dom element projects.

```
var projects = $('#projects');
var tmpl = template({items : list});
console.log("render html ",  $(tmpl));
var div = $('<div class="item">WHY IS THIS NOT WORKING</div>');
projects.masonry( 'appended', div, true );
```

Why would this not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't actually appended the `<div>` to your `#projects` container.

The `'appended'` method on masonry just triggers layout of newly-appended elements.

Try `projects.append(div)` before you call Masonry again.

Answer (score 8):

**Following Solution work for me:**

```
var container = $('.masonry-container');

container.masonry({ 
   columnWidth: '.item', 
   itemSelector: '.item' 
});

$(container).append( data ).masonry("reloadItems").masonry("layout");
```

Comment: It works but sometimes the positions are incorrect. Anyone else had that issue?

Answer (score 2):

Following solutions works for me:-

```
var projects = $('#projects'); 
var elems = []; 
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(); 

var elem = $('<div class="item">WHY IS THIS NOT WORKING</div>').get(0); 
fragment.appendChild(elem); 
elems.push(elem);
projects.appendChild(fragment); 
msnry.appended(elems);
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not understand this until reading your solution. Worked great!